# java in action 8 - lambdas and method reference equivalents

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

As per the Java 8 in action,

(str, i) -> str.substring(i) is equivalent to method reference  String::substring

My code is as follows..

**With Lambda,**

```
String s = "HELLO WORLD";
BiFunction<String, Integer, String> biFunc = (String s, Integer i) -> s.substring(i);
```

**Method Reference**

But the following code gives compile time error saying cannot resolve method substring

```
BiFunction<String, Integer, String> biFunc1 = s1::substring;
```

Kindly help me to understand what I am missing! Thanks

Comment: "(str, i) -> str.substring(i) is equivalent to method reference String::substring" - Is it?

Comment: `(str, i) -> str.substring(i)` is equivalent to `String::substring`, but not to `s1::substring` (whatever `s1` is)

Comment: Thanks Prashanth & Thomas Kläger!!!

Comment: You can also add the missing  "return " :
(String s, Integer i) -> return s.substring(i)

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what `s1` is in `s1::substring`. If `s1` is a `String` instance and you tried to create a method reference for a specific `String` instance, that method reference doesn't match the `BiFunction` functional interface, since calling `biFunc1.apply()` requires you to supply a `String` and an `Integer`, but you already supplied the specific `String` instance in the method reference `s1::substring`.

On the other hand, `s1::substring` matches the `Function<Integer,String>` functional interface.

To create a `BiFunction` of the required type, use a method reference of a non specific instance:

```
BiFunction<String, Integer, String> biFunc1 = String::substring;
```

Examples:

```
String s1 = "abcde";
Function<Integer,String> func1 = s1::substring;
String sub1 = func1.apply(3); // always applied on the same String

BiFunction<String, Integer, String> biFunc1 = String::substring;
String sub2 = biFunc1.apply(s1,3); // applied on whichever String you supply
```

Comment: You made me to understand it better. Thanks Eran